# Publishing Flash to iOS app crashes when more than 45 swfs included

Tags: ios, flash, flash-cs6

I'm experiencing the strangest problem. I've built an app in Flash CS6. The assets folder contains 70 swfs (no code just images and sprites). When I try to publish, Flash crashes. After many attempts, I discovered that the failure point is reached when I include more than 45 swfs e.g. publishes error free until I include the 46th swf. Unfortunately, I do not understand the Java crash report. I'm wondering if I'm missing something fundamental here. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Not sure if attaching the entire crash report is necessary, but hopefully this section will help. I'd love to learn how to read this. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

```
Thread 26 Crashed:
0   libSystem.B.dylib                       0x90d350ee __semwait_signal_nocancel + 10
1   libSystem.B.dylib                       0x90d34fd2 nanosleep$NOCANCEL$UNIX2003 + 166
2   libSystem.B.dylib                       0x90daffb2 usleep$NOCANCEL$UNIX2003 + 61
3   libSystem.B.dylib                       0x90dd1685 __abort + 136
4   libSystem.B.dylib                       0x90dc5d22 __chk_fail + 118
5   libSystem.B.dylib                       0x90d24fe0 __strcat_chk + 41
6   com.adobe.flash.cs6.air                 0x197146a8 CreateAIRFile + 9009
7   com.adobe.flash.cs6.air                 0x19704eee -[SettingsControllerMustard generateFileThd] + 88
8   com.apple.Foundation                    0x918684c4 -[NSThread main] + 45
9   com.apple.Foundation                    0x91868474 __NSThread__main__ + 1499
10  libSystem.B.dylib                       0x90cf5259 _pthread_start + 345
11  libSystem.B.dylib                       0x90cf50de thread_start + 34
 

Thread 26 crashed with X86 Thread State (32-bit):
eax: 0x0000003c  ebx: 0x90d34f39  ecx: 0xb04b357c  edx: 0x90d350ee
edi: 0x20929b50  esi: 0xb04b35d8  ebp: 0xb04b35b8  esp: 0xb04b357c
ss: 0x0000001f  efl: 0x00000247  eip: 0x90d350ee   cs: 0x00000007
ds: 0x0000001f   es: 0x0000001f   fs: 0x0000001f   gs: 0x00000037
cr2: 0x1dab1000
```

Thanks,

Jason

Comment: You could, you know, share the crash report...that would be pretty relevant don't you think?

Comment: The crash report states that the application is failing in "generateFileThd".  Perhaps you could contact Adobe support.  Otherwise you can wait for someone with a similar problem to come along but you delayed too long adding the crash report so now it's very unlikely that anyone will see this question.

Comment: Thanks, borrrden. I'll look into it and report back my findings.

Comment: Just in case anyone reads this thread...I never did learn what the issue was. Upon further input from folks smarter than me, we think it might be an issue with RAM. Unfortunately, Flash CS6 provides 32bit support. I've since taken a different approach to the game utilizing swc's  instead of loading swfs.

Answer (score 0):

Again, I'm not totally sure this was a RAM issue however I converted my swfs to swcs. When I attempted to recompile, I received a useable error message telling me that I had insufficient jvm memory. I then bumped up the memory via the jvm.ini file, restarted Flash, then recompiled my app successfully. I hope this helps another developer.